# How do you format a queryset before returning to admin site for showing?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

How do you format a queryset before returning to admin site for showing?
Here class1 is passed to list_display in model admin class

```
def class1(self,obj):
    return obj.class1_set.all()
```

and returns and shows the unreadable,

```
<QuerySet [<Class: Object>]>
```

to the admin site. All classes already have an __str__override.

Comment: it's undocumented. it only says override__str__.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use %s to format objects of queryset before returning.

Answer (score 0):

You can use allow_tag = True and then use any html tag to format queryset result:

```
def class1(self, obj):
    s=''
    for item in obj.class1_set.all():
        s=s+item.name+'<br>'
    return s
class1.allow_tags = True
```

Comment: allow_tags is deprecated